# Where is whatsapp-purple?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Why can't I find the package `whatsapp-purple` by using this command?

```
sudo apt-get install whatsapp-purple
```

I am using instruction from this site. http://giuseppegangi.com/instalando-whatsapp-en-ubuntu/

Comment: Did you add the repository?

Comment: yes‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: I update with http://www.ftp.ne.jp server.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple
```

Then updating the list with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

reveals that there is no `whatsapp-purple` in that repository. Only available repository was pidgin-whatsapp. You can Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't install because that PPA only has the `pidgin-whatsapp` application.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp
```

Once installed, go ahead and run it, using the Pidgin Internet Messenger entry, and choose Whatsapp from the list.  see image below.

[image]

Comment: I have installed pidgin-whatsapp and logged in. It receives messages but does not send anything. I wanted to test whatsapp-purple instead.

Comment: See if [this](http://freaksense.com/install-whatsapp-on-linux-operating-system/) helps.